# Minecraft 1.10.2 Forge Gradle error

Tags: macos, minecraft, minecraft-forge

So I'm trying to install the forge api (Minecraft 1.10.2) for developing a mod, and I'm having an issue with using ForgeGradle.  Every time I run it with "bash gradlew setupDecompWorkspace", I get this error:

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':forgeGradleMcpData'.

  > Could not resolve de.oceanlabs.mcp:mcp:1.10.2.
  >   Required by:
  >     com.yourname.modid:forge-1:1.0
  >   Could not resolve de.oceanlabs.mcp:mcp:1.10.2.
  >   Could not get resource '(had to remove this link because too many links)'.
  >   Could not GET '(had to remove this link because too many links)'.
  >   org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException (no error message)
  >   Could not resolve de.oceanlabs.mcp:mcp:1.10.2.
  >   Could not get resource 'https://libraries.minecraft.net/de/oceanlabs/mcp/mcp/1.10.2/mcp-1.10.2.pom'.
  >   Could not GET 'https://libraries.minecraft.net/de/oceanlabs/mcp/mcp/1.10.2/mcp-1.10.2.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

I've found several people with the same issue, but they were posted back in (roughly) Minecraft 1.6-1.8.  Does anyone have any idea about what I should do?  I'm stumped and could use some help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `mappings` property in the `minecraft` closure in your `build.gradle` file so ForgeGradle knows which version of the MCP mappings to use.

For example, this will use the latest mappings (as of this posting):

```groovy
minecraft {
    mappings = "snapshot_20161002"
}
```

The snapshot mappings are built daily and the versions are in the form of `snapshot_YYYYMMDD`, you can see all the mappings versions [here](http://export.mcpbot.bspk.rs/).

Comment: Still getting the same error.  Should I change the 'version = "1.10.2-12.18.1.2011"'?

Comment: That shouldn't change anything. In the `buildscript` block (specifically the line that starts with `classpath`), check that you are using ForgeGradle version `2.2-SNAPSHOT`.

Comment: Im still getting the same error, and the class path was correct.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with forge for 1.11. I couldn't use the latest mappings file for some reason. Keeping the mappings file at snapshot_29160518 worked for me.

See this commit for a 1.10.2 plugin build.gradle file:
https://github.com/ljsimin/MinecraftJoypadSplitscreenMod/commit/76b7c83bc35cbe11d6516b31f8e5e4f7ec74b99c